# How to show edit button on uitableviewcell, only on the posts you posted yourself

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm making an app with a login feature, in which you can post, edit, and delete your own favorite spots, and like the posts of other users.

I'm trying to implement an edit button, that only shows on the posts you posted yourself, and hidden on the posts from others.

I have my FeedViewController, in which I call the 'configureCell function' in the UITableviewCell class. This is a part of the code in the FeedViewController:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PostCell") as? PostCell {
        let postList = searchController.active ? searchResult[indexPath.row] : posts[indexPath.row]
        let post = postList
        cell.request?.cancel()

        var image: UIImage?
        if let url = post.postImgUrl {
            image = FeedVC.imageCache.objectForKey(url) as? UIImage
        }

        var image2: UIImage?
        if let url2 = post.userImgUrl {
            image2 = FeedVC.imageCache.objectForKey(url2) as? UIImage
        }

        cell.configureCell(post, img: image, img2: image2)

        return cell
    } else {
        return PostCell()
    }
}
```

This is the code in my UITableviewCell (class PostCell: UITableViewCell):

```
func configureCell(post: Post, img: UIImage?, img2: UIImage?) {
    self.post = post
    likeRef = DataService.ds.REF_USER_CURRENT.childByAppendingPath("likes").childByAppendingPath(post.postKey)

    self.descriptionText.text = post.postDescription
    self.descriptionText.scrollRangeToVisible(NSMakeRange(0, 0))
    self.likesLbl.text = "\(post.likes)"
    self.postTitle.text = post.postTitle
    self.postLocation.text = post.postLocation
    self.username.text = post.username
    self.postKeyLbl.text = post.key

    if post.postImgUrl != nil {
        if img != nil {
            self.showcaseImg.image = img
        } else {
            request = Alamofire.request(.GET, post.postImgUrl!).validate(contentType: ["image/*"]).response(completionHandler: { request, response, data, err in
                if err == nil {
                    let _img = UIImage(data: data!)!
                    self.showcaseImg.image = img
                    FeedVC.imageCache.setObject(_img, forKey: self.post.postImgUrl!)
                } else {
                    print(err.debugDescription)
                }
            })
        }
    } else {
        self.showcaseImg.hidden = true
    }

    if post.userImgUrl != nil {
        if img2 != nil {
            self.profileImg.image = img2
        } else {
            request = Alamofire.request(.GET, post.userImgUrl!).validate(contentType: ["image/*"]).response(completionHandler: { request, response, data, err in
                if err == nil {
                    let _img2 = UIImage(data: data!)!
                    self.profileImg.image = img2
                    FeedVC.imageCache.setObject(_img2, forKey: self.post.userImgUrl!)
                } else {
                    print(err.debugDescription)
                }
            })
        }
    } else {
        print("no image")
    }

    likeRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        if snapshot.value is NSNull {
            self.likesImg.image = UIImage(named: "heart")
        } else {
            self.likesImg.image = UIImage(named: "heart-filled")
        }
    })

    let getUid = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey(KEY_UID)
    if String(getUid!) == (self.post.postUid) {
        editBtn.hidden = false
        delBtn.hidden = false
   }
```

}

It's about the last part:

```
let getUid = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey(KEY_UID)
    if String(getUid!) == (self.post.postUid) {
        editBtn.hidden = false
        delBtn.hidden = false
```

}

That part isn't working. The edit (and delete) button are showing in the posts of the specific user, but also in some of the posts of other users. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Maybe it's because I have also implemented a 'sorting data function', where I am sorting the posts on 'date' or 'likes'. When the posts reshuffle, more edit buttons appear on random cells (from other users).

But I really don't know. I hope someone is able to help me!? Let me know if you need some more code:-) Thanks a lot!

Kind regards,
Dide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an else clause to this:

```
if String(getUid!) == (self.post.postUid) {
    editBtn.hidden = false
    delBtn.hidden = false
} else {
    editBtn.hidden = true
    delBtn.hidden = true
}
```

Because you are reusing cells, some of the cells where the buttons may not be hidden because it is associated with a post of a certain user may be reused for another post of a different user. Since you don't have an else clause handling this situation, those buttons whose 'hidden' property were originally set to false will remain unhidden, even if the postUid and getUid do not match.  Hope this helps!

Comment: It works!! So stupid I didn't try this earlier! Thanks a lot!!